# Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://api.pricing.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: boto3

I am getting this error when I try to get a price from AWS boto3 library.
"Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://api.pricing.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('pricing')
response = client.describe_services()

print(response)
```

Answer (score 7):

There are only two regions available to use that pricing API. See [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/general/latest/gr/rande.html#billing-pricing) and [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/pricing/index.html?highlight=pricing)

```
AWS Price List Service
Region Name             Region      Endpoint                                Protocol
US East (N. Virginia)   us-east-1   api.pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com     HTTPS
Asia Pacific (Mumbai)   ap-south-1  api.pricing.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com    HTTPS
```

You should use only those regions such as:

```
client = boto3.client('pricing', region_name='us-east-1')
```