# Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://acm.eu-west3.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to setup an AWS client VPN by following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/client-authentication.html#mutual

When I enter this command in the Command Prompt (Windows 10):

```
aws acm import-certificate --certificate fileb://server.crt --private-key fileb://server.key --certificate-chain fileb://ca.crt
```

I get this error:

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://acm.eu-west3.amazonaws.com/"
```

When I enter the command `aws configure` then it shows me that the correct region is selected:

```
Default region name [eu-west3]:
```

I didn't find a similar question for acm related issues, but there are many similar questions for application related connection issues. The solution for those issues is often to change the region with `aws configure`.
Related questions:

- [Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://api.pricing.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028283/could-not-connect-to-the-endpoint-url-https-api-pricing-us-west-2-amazonaws)
- [Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://api.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73130769/could-not-connect-to-the-endpoint-url-https-api-ecr-us-west-1-amazonaws-com)
- [AWS Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://rekognition.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60715719/aws-could-not-connect-to-the-endpoint-url-https-rekognition-eu-west-3-amazon)
- [AWS CLI Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://iam.af-south-1.amazonaws.com/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753033/aws-cli-could-not-connect-to-the-endpoint-url-https-iam-af-south-1-amazonaws)

Comment: it's eu-west-3 not eu-west3

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Riz:

In `aws configure` change `eu-west3` to `eu-west-3`